# 'QueryResult' object is not iterable - Not able to return a value in from Dialogflow API to my chatbot

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I'm not able to return `response.query_result`.

I want to return `result["action"]`,`result["query_text"]["fulfillment_text"]`.

I've tried `response.query_result.fulfillment_text` but its showing

> "too many values to unpack"

```
response_id: "39a7bc01-2432-4de2-b134-6d7c5bbee6ea-f308a5c4"
query_result {
  query_text: "you annoy me"
  action: "smalltalk.agent.annoying"
  parameters {
  }
  all_required_params_present: true
  fulfillment_text: "I\'ll try not to annoy you."
  fulfillment_messages {
    text {
      text: "I\'ll try not to annoy you."
    }
  }
  intent {
    name: "projects/my-project-1560026125515/agent/intents/c50c7c63-aa76-4781-ba7d-d9ba4c93df64"
    display_name: "smalltalk.agent.annoying"
  }
  intent_detection_confidence: 1.0
  language_code: "en"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the Response to JSON format.
For this use:

```
import google.protobuf  as pf

response =pf.json_format.MessageToJson(response)
```

Now you can parse this JSON respone.
Hope it helps.